# Determine if datetime is before or after midday

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I'm working in small test code to determine if a generated datetime is before or after the midday like the code below.

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

current_date = datetime.now(timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
new_date = current_date - timedelta(days=2)
print (new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

while new_date <= current_date:
  new_date = new_date + timedelta(minutes=10)
  print (new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  if new_date < datetime.time(12):
    print("test")
```

The problem is, I can't verify if the new_date is under the midday. Probably I'm doing something wrong in the if condition, right?

I would like to print some results if the `new_date`is after midday and another message if it's after midday to midnight.

Any suggestions how I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare just the time from new_date, with 12 converted to a datetime object.
Because of the way you did the imports, when you use datetime.time() it means you are calling datetime.datetime.time() and not datetime.time(), which is why the conversion fails. 
You can solve this by

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
```

and then use

```
time()
```

or by

```
import datetime as dt
```

then using in the appropriate places

```
dt.datetime(), dt.timedelta(), dt.time()
```

Complete code:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
from pytz import timezone

current_date = datetime.now(timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
new_date = current_date - timedelta(days=2)
print (new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

while new_date <= current_date:
  new_date = new_date + timedelta(minutes=10)
  print (new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  if new_date.time() < time(12):
    print("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare to new_date.hour, instead of datetime.time()

```
import random
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

current_date = datetime.now(timezone('America/Sao_Paulo'))
new_date = current_date - timedelta(days=2)
print (new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

while new_date <= current_date:
  new_date = new_date + timedelta(minutes=10)
  print (new_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
  if new_date.hour < 12:
    print("before noon")
  elif new_date.hour >= 18:
    print("after 6 pm")
```